# c++11 std::function like functors incomplete type

Tags: c++11

I've stumbled upon something I can't get through since last week...

Having this:

```
template<typename> struct fx;

template<typename R, typename...Args>
struct fx<R(Args...)>
{
    virtual R operator()(const Args & ...x) const = 0;
};
```

and this:

```
template<typename> struct fx_err;

// I feel here something is wrong, but I can't figure it out.
template<template<typename> class F, typename R, typename... Args>
struct fx_err< F<R(Args...)> > : fx<R(R,Args...)>
{
    using fx_type = F<R(Args...)>;

    fx_type f;

    R operator ()(const R &y, const Args & ...x) const override
    {
        return y - f(x...);
    }
};
```

and this:

```
struct example_fun : fx<int(int,int,int)>
{
    int operator() (const int &a, const int &b, const int &c) const override
    {
        return a * b * c;
    }
};
```

when finally I try to use it like:

```
fx_err<example_fun> example;
int err = example(24,2,3,4);
```

compiler throws error: 'example has incomplete type'.

Something similar works only if I do not specialize fx_err and use pointer to fx_type functor instead, but then I need to add constructor to grab the pointer itself which is not something I want.

It's very frustrating. What's wrong with this? Is it possible what I'm trying to achieve? Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

here's example code to play around with for those willing to experiment with this example: http://pastebin.com/i3bRF8tB

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that example would compile honestly.

Comment: Simply because I thought if int(int,int,int) reduces to a type I can extract template arguments from inside fx template, so it should have worked with additional layer of 'templatization' as well in fx_err template, because the concept is purely analogous (I think so) and example_fun derives from fx<int(int,int,int)> so there should be no problem for compiler to recognize that, right? Obviously I was wrong and that's why I posted the problem here.

Comment: I've created a [complete std::function implementation](https://github.com/potswa/cxx_function) and template template parameters still make my eyes bleed.

Comment: Kudos to you, @Potatoswatter, but after all, do you see any way out of this problem? Sometimes experience comes with some blood of our own spoiled, so... I will appreciate any kind of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid template template parameters if you can. They add more complexity, and less flexibility, than you probably want.

It looks like you're trying to match the form of the `fx` base class against its derived class. Partial specialization requires exact matches, it won't slice to the base class. And even if it did, this member would be of abstract class type:

```
using fx_type = F<R(Args...)>;
fx_type f; // same as fx<R(Args...)> which is abstract
```

The solution is to preserve the derived class, and tell the partial specialization how to find the base. Then the partial specialization can do pattern matching on the base class.

```
template<typename derived, typename base = typename derived::fx>
struct fx_err;

template<typename derived, template<typename> class F, typename R, typename... Args>
struct fx_err< derived, F<R(Args...)> > : F<R(R,Args...)>
```

Live solution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/870172bcad0a9034

Of course, finding the base class by `typename derived::fx` sort-of begs the question of what base class template was used. In theory, you could have several templates of the same name, or `derived` could have a member `typedef my_base fx;` instead of inheriting from an `fx` specialization.

More likely, though, you don't need `template<typename> class F` at all.

```
template<typename derived, typename base = typename derived::fx>
struct fx_err;

template<typename derived, typename R, typename... Args>
struct fx_err< derived, fx<R(Args...)> > : fx<R(R,Args...)>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem on line:

```
fx_err<example_fun> example;
```

is caused by the fact that `example_fun` is "passed" to `fx_err`, which selects the declaration:

```
template<typename> struct fx_err;
```

which *is* an incomplete type.

The specialization you provide:

```
// I feel here something is wrong, but I can't figure it out.
template<template<typename> class F, typename R, typename... Args>
struct fx_err< F<R(Args...)> > : fx<R(R,Args...)>
{ ... }
```

cannot be selected, because `example_fun` is not a template class as required by:

```
template<typename> class F
```

Answer (score 0):

`fx_err<example_fun>` does not match your partial specialization because `example_fun` is not of the form `F<R(Args...)>`.  It inherits a type of that form, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: yep this seems correct, but do you see any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When selecting specializations for class templates, implicit conversions aren't considered. Therefore `example_fun` isn't seen as a `fx<...>` by the compiler when matching the specializations and the primary (undefined) template is chosen over the other specialization.

To solve this you can expose an alias for the base class in the derived class:

```c++
struct example_fun : fx<int(int,int,int)>
{
    using type = fx<int(int,int,int)>;
};
```

And now use this alias at the declaration site:

```c++
fx_err<example_fun::type> example;
int err = example(24,2,3,4);
```

You can even use a macro to avoid repeating the base class name:

```c++
template<class T> struct tag { using type = T; };
#define BASE_TAG(B) B, public tag<B>

struct example_fun : BASE_TAG(fx<int(int, int, int)>) {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Why do that ugly macro stuff, when you can do ugly SFINAE stuff?  Bounce the passed in type to `fx_err` through a function that has a similar pattern `template<?> tag<F<R(Args...)>> foo(F<R(Args...)>)`, it will extract bases, and have it return the type of the matched base wrapped in a tag, extract it, and use it within `fx_err`.

Comment: thanks for advice, @0x499602D2, but your solution doesn't work, after exposing alias as you suggested, fx_type f inside fx_err becomes an abstract type and compiler doesn't see the implementation

Comment: @Yakk, can you post some code explaining what you're talking about? Not sure if I understand your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that template type pattern matching does *not* work like function overload template pattern matching.  Inheritance is ignored, only the type passed in is pattern matched against.

So `struct foo: some_template<some_args...>` does not match `some_template<some_args...>` during template type pattern matching for the purpose of figuring out which specialization to use.

---

This lets us work with types as values in functions:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
```

Now function template pattern matching works more like what you seem to be expecting:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Args>
constexpr tag<Z<Args...>> get_template( Z<Args...>const& ) { return {}; }
```

takes a single argument, does template function pattern matching and deduction against it.  This **will** look at parents of the type passed in.  It tries to match `Z<Args...>` for some template `Z`.

It returns a `tag<Z<Args...>>`, which is a stateless type that just stores the type we need.  We can then feed the above through an alias to extract that template expansion:

```
template<class T>
using get_template_t = type_t<decltype(get_template(std::declval<T>()))>;
```

which is most of the way there.

Next, we need some SFINAE helper magic:

```
template<class...>struct voider:tag<void>{};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=type_t<voider<Ts...>>;
```

`std::void_t` is C++14, and takes a bunch of types and throws them away, returning `void` instead.  I do it in 2 lines because some compilers fail on the one-line version.

Ok, now we attack `fx_err`:

```
template<class,class=void> struct fx_err;
```

the second `class=void` lets us do FSINAE work.  We start with your

```
template<template<class...>class F, class R, class...Args>
struct fx_err< F<R(Args...)>, void > : fx<R(R,Args...)>
{
  using fx_type = F<R(Args...)>;

  fx_type f;

  R operator ()(const R &y, const Args & ...x) const override {
    return y - f(x...);
  }
};
```

and we also do this:

```
template<class T>
struct fx_err< T, void_t<get_template_t<T>>> : fx_err<get_template_t<T>>
{};
```

which I think should work.  If it doesn't, we just need to add a test to exclude the direct `T<F(Args...)>` case from this specialization.

Comment: Thank you Yakk, but your solution still doesn't work, although I have not added the test you've mentioned. Fortunately, @Potatoswatter idea works perfectly, so let's all learn from this!